# Setup Project with Access Database VS 2012

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

I have C# Desktop application with Access Database. How I can make setup project and attach the database in a way that the system can be install on any computer automatically.
I'm using visual Studio 2012

Comment: What - if anything - have you tried so far?  If I am reading correctly, you want the database project to install _with_ the application?

Comment: Yes I try before that. and I made a setup project and I attach the database. but it's not working well with me. I wanat to attach the database and installed with the setup. and to be able to run on any computer that it's installed on it. I still don't find clear answer and steps for that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're wanting to add the database to the install file, so that when you install it, the database is there with you? If so, create a deployment installation project.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/2kt85ked(v=vs.80).aspx for more details. 
Using the windows installer, you can add files to the installation and they will be installed to a set (by you) location.

Comment: Thank you , but I my question exactly ; Should I change the connection string , and how to change it ? to be able to run on any computer that is installed on it

Comment: Why would you need to change the connection string? Can you post it?